# MySQL returns zero rows(Empty set) without limit because of broken/outdated index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I work on a large table with around 1.5k entries,

```
CREATE TABLE `crawler` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
`provider_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `crawler_provider_id` (`provider_id`),
...
) ENGINE=MyISAM ...
```

provider_id is used to link this table to another table 'providers, which was cleared and repopulated with new data. I was trying to recreate connections from 'crawler' to 'providers' (which should not really matter in case of MyISAM), but for some reason in my script MySQL returns zero rows if i don't provide a limit.

```
mysql> SELECT `crawler`.`id` FROM `crawler` WHERE `crawler`.`provider_id` > 1371;
Empty set (0.40 sec)
```

but

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `crawler` WHERE `crawler`.`provider_id` > 1371;
|   346999 |
```

and

```
mysql> SELECT `crawler`.`id` FROM `crawler` WHERE `crawler`.`provider_id` > 1371 LIMIT 10;
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

If I select some data from table and check it by myself I can see values greater than 1371.

**I was able to fix this by deleting indexes** (and recreating later), but I am extremely confused. I've never seen indexes going out of sync with table data (and I was unaware that they can affect values of returned rows). Unfortunately I haven't performed "CHECK TABLE" before deleting indexes, but it has "status=ok" right now, I can't see anything wrong in logs, and "REPAIR TABLE" shows no problems.

So, is this a common problem? What can be the reason? This server had some low RAM problems before, could it be the issue here as well?

Comment: Should probably be in Server Fault

Comment: Did the database crash recently? MyISAM is notorious for getting corrupt on crashes.

Comment: No, this server worked without crashes even when it was low on memory, just extremely slow. But applications, which connect to this server were crashing a lot due to being killed by timeouts, sometimes during insert or update queries if this matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is almost certainly related to table corruption in MyISAM.

I did

```
root@localhost [kris]> create table crawler (
  id integer not null auto_increment primary key, 
  provider_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id), 
  KEY crawler_provider_id (provider_id)
) engine = myisam;
root@localhost [kris]> insert into crawler ( id, provider_id ) values ( NULL, 1 );</code>
```

and then repeated

```
root@localhost [kris]> insert into crawler ( id, provider_id) 
  select NULL, rand() * 120000 from crawler;
```

until I had

```
root@localhost [kris]> select count(*) from crawler;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   524288 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I now have

```
root@localhost [kris]> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `crawler` WHERE `crawler`.`provider_id` > 1371;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   518389 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.27 sec)
```

which is somewhat comparable in size to what you gave in your example above. I do get two different plans for the query with and without a LIMIT clause.

Without a LIMIT clause I get a full table scan (ALL) not using any index:

```
root@localhost [kris]> explain SELECT `crawler`.`id` FROM `crawler` WHERE `crawler`.`provider_id` > 1371\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: crawler
         type: ALL
possible_keys: crawler_provider_id
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 524288
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

With the LIMIT clause, the INDEX is used for a RANGE access

```
root@localhost [kris]> explain SELECT `crawler`.`id` FROM `crawler` WHERE `crawler`.`provider_id` > 1371 LIMIT 10\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: crawler
         type: range
possible_keys: crawler_provider_id
          key: crawler_provider_id
      key_len: 5
          ref: NULL
         rows: 518136
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In your example, without the LIMIT clause (full table scan) you get no data, but with the LIMIT clause (range access using index) you get data. That points to a corrupted MYD file.

ALTER TABLE, as REPAIR TABLE or OPTIMIZE TABLE, will normally copy the data and the kept indexes from the source table to a hidden new version of the table in a new format. When completed, the hidden new table will replace the old version of the table (which will be renamed to a hidden name, and then dropped).

That is, by dropping the indexes you effectively repaired the table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can delete and recreate the index, and after that repair or optimize the table so all indices get rebuilt.  That may help you. And look at your configuration to see if the memory settings are appropriate.